# Как объединить два языка программирования в одном проекте

Tags: java, c++, клиент-сервер

Делал клиент-серверное приложение на Java. Серверную часть писал на протоколе UDP, клиентскую часть реализовывал с помощью библиотеки JavaFX. Теперь у меня задание переделать клиентскую часть, а именно реализовать ее на С++ с библиотекой GraphicsLib. Вопрос в следующем: можно ли как-то объединить эти два ЯП? Если да, то подскажите, каким образом. Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Используйте 2 каталога (директории). Т.е. формально это 2 разных проекта, один на Java, другой на C++

Comment: Что значит "объединить", и зачем? Звучит как две независимые программы.

Comment: Если Вы можете писать на java то  вашим  инструментом будет  Java  native  interfaces =JNI либо его   более современная  версия Java Natice Access - JNA.  Если же  Вы хотите  из C++  достучаться до java  то есть  многочисленные  сторонние бибиотеки   решающие вашу  задачу.

Comment: *"реализовать ее на С++"* не подразумевает никакой необходимости что-то объединять...